# Recent Documents list in ArcMap is not being updated

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

On a colleague's machine, the list of Recent Documents isn't being populated when closing an MXD.

- she opens map1.mxd
- saves the document and closes ArcMap
- re-opens ArcMap

map1.mxd isn't shown in the *> Existing Maps > Recent* section on the welcome screen, or under the *> File* menu.

Where is the list of recent documents stored? (Interestingly, her welcome screen does list 2 documents, just not the most recently-accessed ones.)

Of course this is all within a corporate system with network drives, locked-down permissions, etc.... ArcMap 10.2.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: The ArcGIS Discussion Forum had a [short thread with no solution](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/51518) on this a couple of years ago.

Comment: I've noticed this too. What happens if she opens, saves and closes that same document once again? Sometimes it will show up in the list after the second time.

Comment: @Martin no change - it still doesn't show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can actually be controlled via the operating system. It's entirely possible that a Windows setting (user/machine policy, or just a basic option) has been set or altered such that it won't store recent document history. If it showing some, that would suggest it was altered. The settings can control both the number of items to keep in the list as well as whether any are kept at all. Note it can be set for both Start Menu 'Recent Documents' as well as individual programs though that's usually set in the program itself.

For the actual question of where it's stored, the answer is the registry under the user profile ([source](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/34242)).

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Recent File List

Unfortunately on a locked down machine this is unlikely to do you any good since regedit is typically one of the first things to go, though it may be an indication of a corrupted or corrupting profile. Might also try a full reboot, not just closing and restarting the program. Arc has a problem truly shutting down sometimes, even after the program is closed.

Comment: The first thing I do in a new job is make friends with the sysadmin - I'll go pester him now ;)

Comment: It would be nice to be able to have more than 10 recent documents, but it doesn't seem to be set up to be able to change that.